# Generate a 404 header that shows the browser default 404 page

Tags: php

I am trying to generate a 404 header, and I want the browser to display the **browser** default page for the error, but no matter what I have tried I always end up displaying an "empty" html document which is not what I want.

This is my code:

```
if (strlen($buffer) == 0)
            {
                ob_clean();
                header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
                ob_flush();
                die();
            }
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Why do you think there is a "default" browser 404 page? HTTP 404 is a server status, it's up to the server to provide the information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "browser default" 404 page. The 4xx or 5xx error pages are generated on the server. You could possibly look at e.g. Apache's default 404 page for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [http_response_code(404);](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) instead?

Answer (score 0):

There are no such thing. Quoting from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404

> The web site hosting server will typically generate a "404 Not Found"
>   web page when a user attempts to follow a broken or dead link

That said, as @Petter mentioned, most webservers have a default 404 page if you don't provide a custom one.

Answer (score -1):

Trigger a 404 header:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```

Kill the rest of the script:

```
die();
```

Just triggering the 404 header will not will the browser, but die will